# Does the BitTorrent protocol expose my home IP address, even over VPN/Tor?

Tags: data-leakage, bittorrent

I am filesharing from home using a BitTorrent client in one of three scenarios:

1. I am using my regular ISP connection
2. I am using a tunnel (VPN) connection
3. I am using a Tor connection (a)

Obviously I expose my home IP address in scenario 1, how else would my peers be able to share with me? But I have this notion (citation needed) that even in scenarios 2 and 3, the way the BitTorrent protocol works means that it exposes my home IP address anyway. Is this true?

**Footnotes**

(a) [Do not do this.](https://blog.torproject.org/bittorrent-over-tor-isnt-good-idea)

Comment: You may want to consider using a seedbox instead.

Comment: It does not in #2 & #3. The originating IP field is kept empty.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to #2 depends a little bit on your VPN provider and how the routing is configured. VPNs that you subscribe to for privacy *should* hide your IP properly.

The easiest answer is found by performing a test. Do a google search for "bittorrent ip leak" and you'll find results for tests that provide you with your IP address when using a BitTorrent client.

For #3, the answer depends a bit too. It's worth noting that in 2010 the Tor project itself doesn't recommend using Tor for BitTorrent: https://blog.torproject.org/bittorrent-over-tor-isnt-good-idea. It's possible that your BitTorrent client may ignore your proxy settings, for example. I'd recommend to test this by performing a similar test as in #2.